# Passing QList <QObject *> from C ++ to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Good evening,

We are programming a DaVinci DM8168 board with Qt5.7.1 and QtQuick2.7

we would like to pass a list of type:
QList  from C ++ to QML
to be able to draw it asynchronously and above all efficiently. The list is modified by a thread on C ++.
We cannot state the update frequence of this list at all: it can be just one time per second or dozens! It depends by the target enviroment.

our solution (partially working) is the following:

On the C++ side we are using QPROPERTIES:

an extract of our code:

```
MyClass.h
class MyClass: public Observer
{
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject*> getFailuresHistory READ getFailuresHistory NOTIFY       failuresHistoryListChanged)

QList<QObject*>getFailuresHistory(){return failuresHistory_;}
signals:
void failuresHistoryListChanged();
}
```

then my .cpp we emit the signal every time the list changes ( not true at all: if more elements of the list changes at the same time we emit the signal only once in order to optimize the application)

```
emit failuresHistoryListChanged();
```

Then on QML "side" we do the following:

```
Item
{



// ... other code

//DELAGATE
        Component
        {
            id: failuresDelegateHistory
            Item
            {
                id:                           listHistoryItem
                width:                        listHistory.width
                height:                       10
                anchors.leftMargin: 5
                Row
                {
                    Text{
                        id: failureIdHistory
                        width: 30
                        text: qsTr(modelData.codeFailure) + mainSettingsHandler.emptyString
                        color: mainWindow.currentStyleColor.colorRed
                        font.pixelSize: 16
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    }

                    Text {
                        id: descriptionFailIdHistory
                        width: (listHistoryItem.width-failureIdHistory.width)*0.5

                        color:mainWindow.currentStyleColor.colorWhite
                        maximumLineCount: 1
                        text: qsTr(modelData.descriptionFail) + mainSettingsHandler.emptyString
                        wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignJustify
                        font.pixelSize: 12//16
                    }
                    Text
                    {
                        id: columnTimeStampFailureHistory
                        width: (listHistoryItem.width-descriptionFailIdHistory.width-failureIdHistory.width- 2)
                        maximumLineCount: 1
                        text: modelData.dateFail + mainSettingsHandler.emptyString
                        wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
                        color:mainWindow.currentStyleColor.colorWhite
                        font.pixelSize: 12
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignJustify
                    }
                }

            }
        }

//LIST
        ListView
        {
            id: list1

            y: labelHistory.y + labelHistory.height+5
            width: (FileConfiguration.widthMenuArea - space - 5)*0.5-1-space
            height: (270 - space) *itemsPerPage
            model: myClass.getFailuresHistory//failuresHistoryTable.getFailuresHisory
            delegate: failuresDelegateHistory
            spacing: 10
            enabled: false
        }           

// ... other code
}
```

OK;
as I said before this solution is partially working because is very, very slow! 
When the:

```
emit failuresHistoryListChanged();
```

on c++ side is called, the list is drawn but the software is "slow". We have keepalive message that shall be set every 300 ms and that is not sent anymore for a couple of seconds.
We need a more efficent way to pass the list to the QML.
if we comment the emit the software works fine within its deadlines.

So our purpose is: we would like to pass in a very efficent way this list to QML. Do you have solutions that involve a modification of the code that we have shown you or new architectures? do you have any examples? we are not experts in qml.

If you need more information ask us.

We thank you in advance, we have been trying to solve the problem for a long time.
thanks

Comment: try changing `QList<QObject*>` to `QObjectList`

Comment: Especially if the list is large and/or changes only partially over time (rows being appended/removed, updated…): Consider implementing the list as QAbstractListModel.